# react native map method not rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, native

I'm doing a simple cryptocurrency app to display daily price and change. When rendering the view with 0 index with the info for the first coin the data is displayed, but when using the map method, nothing is displayed... here is the code for the view:

```
              <View style={styles.container}>
               <ScrollView contenContainerStyle={styles.coinList}>
                {this.state.coinList.map((coin, index) => {
                  alert (coin.symbol + ': ' + coin.price);
                  <CoinInfo
                    key={index}
                    symbol={coin.symbol}
                    name={coin.name}
                    price={coin.price}
                    change={coin.change}
                    active={false}
                    onPress={this.fonPress}
                  />;
                })}
              </ScrollView>
            <View/>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 62,
    backgroundColor: '#40137A',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  loading: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  coinList: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  }
});
```

I used an alert to see if the map is working and it alerts me 7 of the 8 coins i had in the array...

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 2):

When using the Array.map method you should return the element to be added to the resulting array.

You see the alerts because the function is running, but since you are not returning the child elements the resulting array has nothing to be rendered.

Try this:

```
            {this.state.coinList.map((coin, index) => {
              alert (coin.symbol + ': ' + coin.price);
              return <CoinInfo
                key={index}
                symbol={coin.symbol}
                name={coin.name}
                price={coin.price}
                change={coin.change}
                active={false}
                onPress={this.fonPress}
              />;
            })}
```

I recommend you to take a look into the following link to understand Array.map better:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Amy, works very well now. I'll keep learning  :)

Comment: My pleasure :) glad to be helpful!